# Unable to access Google Cloud Platform after Upgrading to a Workspace Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I've had a GCP account for more than a year or so and decided to upgrade to a Workspace Account. After the upgrade, I keep getting the following message when I try to access the Google Cloud Platform Console

**Google couldn’t verify this account belongs to you.
Try again later or use Account Recovery for help.**

I then run the recovery process successfully, only to be sent back to the same recovery screen above when I try to access the Console at cloud.google.com. I have most of my code in Google Cloud Source Repositories and was using some of the services , e.g. compute  engine, cloud functions,  pub/sub and Dataproc to name a few in that account.

How can I get back into the Console for this account?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

[I had a similar question and found the answer to that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69769436/how-to-turn-off-google-cloud-platform-security-key-enforcement/69821739#69821739)

In short, google has an additional setting for reauthentication. If the the method for reauthentication is set to "Security Key" than it won't allow any user in without a security key.

You can find the setting here:

[image: Re-authentication settings]

If you change it to "Password" users should be able to login again.