# How to turn off google cloud platform security key enforcement?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity

## Problem

I have an organization in google cloud and cloud identity. In the [identity admin panel](https://admin.google.com) I have selected to not enforce 2fa but to allow users to enable it.

[image: 2FA enforcement]

However, if a user wants to log in to [google cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com) and don't have a security key as 2fa. They are greeted with this screen

[image: Google cloud failed login screen]

And if a user has a security key as 2fa then they are allowed access to the google cloud console panel.

## Question

How can I turn off the enforcement/requirement of a security key for users to be able to log in to google cloud?

## EDIT

**I have created a video that shows the problem: https://youtu.be/oRt_193-SYI**

Comment: Users do not log into Google Cloud. They are already logged in. You must turn off 2FA for that user if you do not want 2FA enforced. 2FA is not optional, you either require it or disable it.

Comment: I want to require it. But more forms of 2FA than just a security key. Like prompt or OTC. Is that also not possible or is it either no 2FA at all or only 2FA with a security key?

Comment: You have 2FA set up wrong or the user has not authenticated completely. Your question does not include the details necessary to help you. Your question states: **except for text messages and phone calls**. Users must use of the available options, you are limiting those options. You state **prompt or OTC**. Do you have that enabled and configured? Note that the device a user is using to access the Google Cloud Console GUI might limit available options. For example, you cannot use **Google Prompt**, which requires Android or iPhone, when using a desktop.

Comment: This link might help you: https://support.google.com/a/answer/175197

Comment: I have created a test user account using: https://admin.google.com. On that account, I have enabled 2FA (google-prompt & Authenticator-app). When I try to login to https://console.cloud.google.com I get the second screenshot as a page, and can not go to the console.

However, when I add a security key as a 2FA option on my test account. Then sign-in to GCP it allows me through and goes to the console. 

How do I make it so I don't have to add a security key as a 2FA option?

Comment: IMBW: Verify your identity before going to the Google Cloud Console GUI. The key is to complete the authentication and verification process at least once.

Comment: But what if users don't have access to a security key? How do they verify it once? Or is there an option to let them skip it?

Comment: If they do not have access to the 2FA, why do you expect them to pass the 2FA checks? Your logic is confusing to me. 2FA is either pass or fail - there is no **skip**.

Comment: They can set their 2FA to whatever they want. But If they don't have a security key as an option. The cloud console won't let them in. They can't go to https://console.cloud.google.com without having a security key as a 2FA option on their account. If they do go to the cloud console without a security key on their account, they just get the page shown in picture 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the settings menu where this is located.
Google has settings for session controls and how often users need to re-authenticate. One of the options is with the kind of re-authentication method users must use. Mine was set to "security key".

Hence, when users wanted to log in they were forced to authenticate with a security key that they did not have.

[This is where it is located](https://admin.google.com/ac/security/reauth/admin-tools):

[image: Re-authentication settings]

Answer (score 0):

You can create [backup verification codes](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2537800#getbackupcodes&zippy=%2Cget-backup-verification-codes-for-a-user) for users who don't have access to their security keys:

> Users who temporarily can’t access their second authentication method
> may get locked out. For example, a user may have left their security
> key at home, or can’t receive an access code by phone. For these
> users, you can generate backup verification codes to allow them to
> sign in.
>
> 1. To view the user's backup verification codes, click **2-Step
>    Verification** and then **Get backup verification codes**.
> 2. Copy one of the
>    existing backup codes or generate new codes. **Note**: select **Get new
>    codes** If you think the existing backup codes were stolen or have been
>    used up. The old set of backup codes automatically become inactive.
> 3. Tell your user to follow the instructions in [Sign in using backup
>    codes](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538). If the user is required to use a [security key](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6103523) for 2-step
>    verification, you'll see the grace period that's left before they need
>    to use their security key to sign in.

Comment: Sadly, no. It misunderstood the question. Probably because I am readily terrible at describing the problem. I made a video which (hopefully) shows it better: https://youtu.be/oRt_193-SYI

Comment: You need to check the [user's security settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2537800) and see if [enforcement is enabled](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9176657?visit_id=637719633470263018-607193656&rd=1#zippy=%2Cturn-on-enforcement). Please update the question afterward.

Comment: No, enforcement is disabled for all users. Including my test account. I have updated the question to clarify that.